# only valid numeric escape in strict mode is '\0'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to insert some data. Data is object. When I try add data it throws error like this `The only valid numeric escape in strict mode is '\0'`. When I remove `\1` I can insert the data. I don't want to remove that data. Is there any way to insert this data?

```js
[
  {
    data: "File\1"
  }
]
```

Comment: You should add the code where you're trying to insert data to your question.

Comment: Double escape it `"File\\1"`